# Is $f$ is a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology

Why $f:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x)=(x,1/x)$ is continuous function?

If I draw a image I get two asymptotes, and I cant touch (0,0). It is a counterexample of "the image under continuous function, of arc-connected set, is arc-connected set"?

Comment: It is most certainly not a counterexample to that *true* fact. By the way, the function is indeed continuous.

Comment: The two components of $f $ are continuous at $R-\{0\} $ thus $f $ is continuous.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is continuous, but $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ is not arc-connected. There is no path from $-1$ to $1$ in $\mathbb R-\{0\}$. So the image of $f$ need not be arc-connected, and indeed it isn't.